# Error: error putting S3 bucket (s3-bucket-master-xxxxxx) logging: CrossLocationLoggingProhibitted: Cross S3 location logging not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am creating two S3 buckets to keep logs, I want SRR Same Region Replication. Whilst I am not so much familiar with S3 service my code has worked except for the last stage of adding logging to make **tfsec** and **checkov**,  ***compliant***

**s3.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role_replication" {
  name = "tf-iam-role-replication-12345"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy_replication" {
  name = "tf-iam-role-policy-replication-12345"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
         "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.arn}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete",
        "s3:ReplicateTags"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.arn}/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "replication" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.iam_role_replication.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_replication.arn
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_slave" {
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-slave-"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "s3_bucket_slave_sse_config" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.bucket

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "s3_bucket_slave_versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_master" {
  provider      = aws.apac
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-master-"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "s3_bucket_master_sse_config" {
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.bucket
  provider = aws.apac
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "s3_bucket_master_versioning" {
  provider = aws.apac

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "s3_bucket_master_replication" {
  provider = aws.apac
  # Must have bucket versioning enabled first
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.s3_bucket_master_versioning]

  role   = aws_iam_role.iam_role_replication.arn
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id

  rule {
    id = "foobar"
    delete_marker_replication {
      status = "Disabled"
    }
    filter {
      prefix = "foo"
    }

    status = "Enabled"

    destination {
      bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.arn
      storage_class = "STANDARD"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_bucket_master_acl" {
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  acl      = "private"
  provider = aws.apac
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_bucket_slave_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_bucket_master_public_access" {
  provider                = alias.apac
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id
  restrict_public_buckets = true
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_bucket_slave_public_access" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  restrict_public_buckets = true
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "example" {
  provider = alias.apac
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_master.id

  target_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_slave.id
  target_prefix = "log/"
}
```

**provider.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.22.0"
    }
    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = "3.1.1"
    }
    alias = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.22.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "null" {
  # Configuration options
}

# Configure AWS provider:

provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "apac"
  region = "ap-southeast-1"
}
```

**kms.tf**

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "kms_key" {
  description             = "This key is used to encrypt bucket objects"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation     = true
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting errors like the below:

```
╷
│ Warning: Duplicate required provider
│
│   on provider.tf line 4, in terraform:
│    4:     aws = {
│    5:       source  = "hashicorp/aws"
│    6:       version = "4.22.0"
│    7:     }
│
│ Provider hashicorp/aws with the local name "aws" was previously required as "alias". A provider can only be required once within required_providers.   
│
│ (and one more similar warning elsewhere)
╵
╷
│ Error: error putting S3 bucket (s3-bucket-master-20220712130829925900000001) logging: CrossLocationLoggingProhibitted: Cross S3 location logging not allowed.
│       status code: 403, request id: 85528RE6KMQJDMJM, host id: 3cpcDdHT3Wl442f7L/x3VLCp26wCghaIPTwKKhnWLOmsTW4cSI9f5pFROHr7q4fDLQJMyfNBZIA=
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket_logging.example,
│   on s3.tf line 166, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "example":
│  166: resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "example" {
│
╵
```

What help I am seeking from more experienced people is

1. What part code do I need to delete to make SRR? thereby resolve the error.
2. Any idea how to suppress the warning for alias?

Do note if I remote the section

```
    alias = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.22.0"
    }
```

I get errors like the below for **  terraform init **

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/alias: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named 
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/alias
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which        
│ modules are currently depending on hashicorp/alias, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵


terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] 4.22.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null] 3.1.1
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/alias]

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
```

Comment: You said you want SRR, but your s3_bucket_master and s3_bucket_slave are in two different regions. I'm confused.

Comment: Ok, thanks jellycsc. So I should keep them in the same region thereby removing alias (provider)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define the `aws` twice in the `required_providers` block, it's enough to be defined only once:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.22.0"
    }
    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = "3.1.1"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you need to remove the `.terraform` directory **prior** to re-running `terraform init` to make sure you have a clean slate. Lastly, make sure if you want SRR and not CRR to use either the aliased or non-aliased provider, but not both.

So you are currently defining one of the buckets as:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_slave" {
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-slave-"
}
```

And the second one as:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_master" {
  provider      = aws.apac # <---- note the aliased provider, hence a different region
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-master-"
}
```

In order to fix that, either remove the aliased provider from the second bucket or add it to the first one. As you current configuration is using `aws.apac` in more places than it is not, I would suggest adding the aliased provider to the first bucket if the region is not important:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket_slave" {
  provider      = aws.apac
  bucket_prefix = "s3-bucket-slave-"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marko! It worked like a charm, learnt new thing as well. Happy Learning :)